# parallelized tasks are not ditributed a cross available cpus

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

As shown in the code posted below in section `DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool`, the run() is called as much times as the contents of the `self.__listOfLoopDecouplers` and it works as it supposed to be, i mean the parallelization is working duly.
as shown in the same section, `DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.pool.map` returns results and i populate some lists,lets discuss the list names `self.__iterablesOfZeroCoverageCell` it contains number of objects of type `gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel`.

After that, i created the pool `ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool` with the code as posted below as well.

The problem i am facing, is the parallelized code in `ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool` is very slow and the visulisation of the cpu tasks shows that there are no processes work in parallel as shown in the video contained in url posted below.
i was suspicious about the pickling issues related to when parallelizing the code in `ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool`,so i removed the enitre body of the run() in `ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool`. however, it shows no change in the behaviour of the parallelized code.

also the url posted below shown how the parallelized methoth of `ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool` behaves.

given the code posted below, please let me know why the parallelization does not work for code in `ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool`

**output url:please click the link**

[output url](https://vimeo.com/773225532/cc0962fa62)

**DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool**

```
def postTask(self):
    self.__postTaskStartTime = time.time()
    
    with Pool(processes=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['proceses_count'])) as DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.pool:
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSize(lst=self.__listOfLoopDecouplers,cpuCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['cpu_count']))
        logger.info(f"DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.self.__chunkSize(task per processor):{self.__chunkSize}")
        for res in DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.pool.map(self.run,self.__listOfLoopDecouplers,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
            if res[0] is not None and res[1] is None and res[2] is None:
                self.__iterablesOfNoneZeroCoverageCell.append(res[0])
            elif res[1] is not None and res[0] is None and res[2] is None:
                self.__iterablesOfZeroCoverageCell.append(res[1])
            elif res[2] is not None and res[0] is None and res[1] is None:
                self.__iterablesOfNoDataCells.append(res[2])                
            else:
                raise Exception (f"WTF.")
    DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.pool.join()
    assert len(self.__iterablesOfNoneZeroCoverageCell)+len(self.__iterablesOfZeroCoverageCell)+len(self.__iterablesOfNoDataCells) == len(self.__listOfLoopDecouplers)  
    
    zeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool = ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool(self.__devModeForWSAWANTIVer2,self.__iterablesOfZeroCoverageCell)
    zeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.postTask()
    
def run(self,param:LoopDecoupler):
    row = param.getRowValue()
    col = param.getColValue()
    elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents = param.getElevationsTIFFWindowedSegment()
    verticalStep = param.getVericalStep()
    horizontalStep = param.getHorizontalStep()
    mainTIFFImageDatasetContents = param.getMainTIFFImageDatasetContents()
    NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832 = param.getNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832()
    URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832 = param.getURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832()
    threshold = param.getThreshold()
    rowsCnt = 0
    colsCnt = 0     

    pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = 0
    pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])
    pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])
    _pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell = []
    _pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell = []
    _pixelsValuesInNoDataCell = []
    
    gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel = None
    gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel = None
    gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel = None
    for x in range(row,row + verticalStep):
        if rowsCnt == verticalStep:
            rowsCnt = 0
        for y in range(col,col + horizontalStep):
            if colsCnt == horizontalStep:
                colsCnt = 0
            
            pixelValue = mainTIFFImageDatasetContents[0][x][y]
            # windowIOUtils.writeContentsToFile(windowIOUtils.getPathToOutputDir()+"/"+config['window']['file_name']+".{0}".format(config['window']['file_extension']), "pixelValue:{0}\n".format(pixelValue))
            if pixelValue >= float(threshold):
                pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt+=1
                _pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell.append(elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents[0][rowsCnt][colsCnt])
            elif ((pixelValue < float(threshold)) and (pixelValue > float(config['TIFF']['no_data_value']))):
                pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt-=1
                _pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell.append(elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents[0][rowsCnt][colsCnt])
            elif (pixelValue <= float(config['TIFF']['no_data_value'])):
                    pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt-=1
                    _pixelsValuesInNoDataCell.append(elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents[0][rowsCnt][colsCnt])
            else:
                raise Exception ("WTF.Exception: unhandled condition for pixel value: {0}".format(pixelValue))
            # _pixelCoordinatesInWindow.append([x,y])
            colsCnt+=1
        rowsCnt+=1
    
    '''Grid-cell classfication'''
    if (pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt > 0):
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel = GridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel()
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setRowValue(row)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setColValue(col)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setVericalStep(verticalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setHorizontalStep(horizontalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setMainTIFFImageDatasetContents(mainTIFFImageDatasetContents)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832(NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832(URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt(pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell(_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell)

    elif (pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt < (int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])) and pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt >= 0):
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel = GridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel()
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setRowValue(row)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setColValue(col)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setVericalStep(verticalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setHorizontalStep(horizontalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setMainTIFFImageDatasetContents(mainTIFFImageDatasetContents)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832(NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832(URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt(pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt(pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell(_pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell)
        
    elif (pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt == 0):
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel = GridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel()
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setRowValue(row)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setColValue(col)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setVericalStep(verticalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setHorizontalStep(horizontalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setMainTIFFImageDatasetContents(mainTIFFImageDatasetContents)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832(NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832(URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setPixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt(pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel.setPixelsValuesInNoDataCell(_pixelsValuesInNoDataCell)
        if gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel is not None:
            gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt(pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
    else:
        raise Exception (f"WTF.")
    
    return gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel,gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel,gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel
```

**ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool**:

```
def postTask(self):
    self.__postTaskStartTime = time.time()
    
    """to collect results per each row
    """
    resAllCellsForGridCellsClassifications = []
    # NDVIs
    resAllCellsForNDVITIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # area of coverage
    resAllCellsForAreaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell = [] 
    # interception
    resAllCellsForInterceptionForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832
    resAllCellsForFourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell = []
    # outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326-lists
    resAllCellsForOutFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells = []
    # fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSON
    resAllCellsForFourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832
    resAllCellsForCalculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # centerPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystem
    resAllCellsForCenterPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystemForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # pixelValuesOfCenterPoints
    resAllCellsForPixelValuesOfCenterPointsForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # centerPointOfKeyWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326
    resAllCellsForCenterPointOfKeyWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # centerPointInEPSG4326
    resAllCellsForCenterPointInEPSG4326ForZeroCoveringCell = []
    # average heights
    resAllCellsForAverageHeightsForZeroCoverageCell = []
    # pixels values
    resAllCellsForPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCell = []
    # area Of Coverage
    resAllCellsForAreaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell = []
    
    resAllCellsForPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = []
    
    noneKeyWindowCnt=0
    # center points as string
    centerPointsAsStringForZeroCoverageCell = ""
    
    with Pool(processes=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['proceses_count'])) as ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool:
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSize(lst=self.__iterables,cpuCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['cpu_count']))
        logger.info(f"ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.self.__chunkSize(task per processor):{self.__chunkSize}")
        for res in ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=self.__iterables,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
            resAllCellsForGridCellsClassifications.append(res[0])
            # NDVIs
            resAllCellsForNDVITIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[1])
            # area of coverage
            resAllCellsForAreaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[2])
            # interception
            resAllCellsForInterceptionForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[3])
            # fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832
            resAllCellsForFourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell.append(res[4])
            # outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326-lists
            resAllCellsForOutFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells.append(res[5])
            # fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326
            resAllCellsForFourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[6])
            # calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832
            resAllCellsForCalculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[7])
            # centerPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystem
            resAllCellsForCenterPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystemForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[8])
            # pixelValuesOfCenterPoints
            resAllCellsForPixelValuesOfCenterPointsForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[9])
            # centerPointInEPSG4326
            resAllCellsForCenterPointInEPSG4326ForZeroCoveringCell.append(res[10])
            # centerPointOfKeyWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326
            resAllCellsForCenterPointOfKeyWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[11])
            # average heights
            resAllCellsForAverageHeightsForZeroCoverageCell.append(res[12])
            # pixels values
            resAllCellsForPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCell.append(res[13])
            # pixelsValues cnt
            resAllCellsForPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt.append(res[14])
            
            noneKeyWindowCnt +=res[15]
            # centerPoints-As-String
            if (res[16] is not None):
                centerPointsAsStringForZeroCoverageCell+=str(res[16])
            
    assert noneKeyWindowCnt == len(self.__iterables)  
    ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.close()
    ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.terminate()
    ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.join()
    
    return 

def run(self,params:GridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel):
    if params is not None:
        logger.info(f"Processing zero coverage cell @(row{params.getRowValue()},col:{params.getColValue()})")
        row = params.getRowValue()
        col = params.getColValue()
        mainTIFFImageDatasetContents = params.getMainTIFFImageDatasetContents()
        NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832 = params.getNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832()
        URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832 = params.getURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832()
        datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832 = rasterio.open(URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832,'r')
        _pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell = params.getPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell()
        pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = params.getPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt()
        countOfNoDataCells = params.getPixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt()
        outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells = []
        fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell = []
        
        ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell = NDVITIFFDetails(None,None,None).getNDVIValuePer10mX10m()
        """area of coverage per grid-cell"""
        areaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell = None
        """"interception"""
        interceptionForZeroCoverageCell = None
        CntOfNDVIsWithNanValueInZeroCoverageCell = 0
        fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell = None
        outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells = []
        fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell = []
        calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell = None
        centerPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystemForZeroCoverageCell = None
        pixelValuesOfCenterPointsOfZeroCoverageCell = None
        centerPointInEPSG4326ForZeroCoveringCell = None
        centerPointOfKeyWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell = None
        centerPointsAsStringForZeroCoverageCell = None
        """average heights"""
        averageHeightsForZeroCoverageCell = None
        gridCellClassifiedAs = GridCellClassifier.ZERO_COVERAGE_CELL.value
        cntOfNoneKeyWindow = 1
        
        ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell = NDVITIFFDetails(ulX=row//int(config['ndvi']['resolution_height']),ulY=col//int(config['ndvi']['resolution_width']),dataset=NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832).getNDVIValuePer10mX10m()
        
        """area of coverage per grid-cell"""
        areaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell = round(AreaOfCoverageDetails(pixelsCount=(int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])) - (pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt + countOfNoDataCells)).getPercentageOfAreaOfCoverage(),2) 
       
        """"interception"""
        if math.isnan(ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell):
            # ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell = 0
            CntOfNDVIsWithNanValueInZeroCoverageCell = 1
            interceptionForZeroCoverageCell = config['sentinel_values']['interception']
        else:
            Indvi = INDVI()
            Ic = Indvi.calcInterception(ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell)
            Pc=areaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell,"""percentage of coverage"""
            Pnc=float((int(config['window']['width'])*int(config['window']['height'])) - areaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell),"""percentage of non-coverage"""
            Inc=float(config['interception']['noneCoverage']),"""interception of none-coverage"""
            I=(float(Pc[0])*(Ic))+float((Pnc[0]*Inc[0]))
            interceptionForZeroCoverageCell = round(I,2)
            if I != 10 and I != float('nan'):
                logger.error(f"ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell:{ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell}")
                logger.error(f"I:{I}")
        
        fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell = RasterIOPackageUtils.convertFourCornersOfWindowFromImageCoordinatesToCRSByCoordinatesOfCentersOfPixelsMethodFor(row,col,int(config['window']['height']),int(config['window']['width']),datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832)
        for i in range(0,len(fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell)):
            
            # fourCornersOfKeyWindowInEPSG4326.append(RasterIOPackageUtils.convertCoordsToDestEPSGForDataset(fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832[i],datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832,destEPSG=4326))
            outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells.append(OSGEOUtils.fromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326(fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell[i])) # resultant coords order is in form of lat,lon and it must be in lon,lat.thus, out[1]-lat out[0]-lon 
        
        """fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326"""
        fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG4326 = [] 
        for i in range(0,len(outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells)):
                    fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG4326.append(([outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells[i][1]],[outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells[i][0]]))
        fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell.append(jsonUtils.buildFeatureCollectionAsGeoJSONForFourCornersOfKeyWindow(fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG4326[0],fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG4326[1],fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG4326[2],fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG4326[3],areaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell))
        # debugIOUtils.writeContentsToFile(debugIOUtils.getPathToOutputDir()+"/"+"NDVIsPer10mX10mForKeyWindow"+config['window']['file_name']+".{0}".format(config['window']['file_extension']),"{0}\n".format(NDVIsPer10mX10mForKeyWindow))        
        """
        building geojson object for a point "center-point" to visualize it.
        """
        calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell = MiscUtils.calculateCenterPointsGivenLLOfGridCell(fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell[1])#lower-left corner
        centerPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystemForZeroCoverageCell = RasterIOPackageUtils.convertFromCRSToImageCoordinatesSystemFor(calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell[0],calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell[1],datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832)
        
        pixelValuesOfCenterPointsOfZeroCoverageCell = mainTIFFImageDatasetContents[0][centerPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystemForZeroCoverageCell[0]][centerPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystemForZeroCoverageCell[1]]
        
        centerPointInEPSG4326ForZeroCoveringCell = RasterIOPackageUtils.convertCoordsToDestEPSGForDataset(calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell,datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832,destEPSG=4326)
        
        centerPointOfKeyWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell = jsonUtils.buildGeoJSONForPointFor(centerPointInEPSG4326ForZeroCoveringCell)
        
        """average heights"""
        averageHeightsForZeroCoverageCell = round(MiscUtils.getAverageFor(_pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell),2)

        assert len(_pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell) > 0 and (len(_pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell) <= (int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])) )
        
        """the following code block is for assertion only"""
        if self.__devModeForWSAWANTIVer2 == config['DEVELOPMENT_MODE']['debug']:
            assert pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt >= 0 and (pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt < (int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])) )
            assert (pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt+countOfNoDataCells) == (int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height']))
            print(f"profiling for gridCellClassifiedAs:{gridCellClassifiedAs}....>pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt:{pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt}")
            print(f"profiling for gridCellClassifiedAs:{gridCellClassifiedAs}....>countOfNoDataCells:{countOfNoDataCells}")
            pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = (int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])) - (pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt + countOfNoDataCells)
            assert pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt == 0, (f"WTF.")
            print(f"profiling for gridCellClassifiedAs:{gridCellClassifiedAs}....>computed pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt:{pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt}")
            print(f"\n")
      
        centerPointAsTextInWKTInEPSG3857 = CoordinatesUtils.buildWKTPointFormatForSinglePointFor(calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell[0],calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell[1])
        s = centerPointAsTextInWKTInEPSG3857.replace("POINT","")
        s = s.replace("(","")
        s = s.replace(")","")
        s = s.strip()
        s = s.split(" ")
        centerPointsAsStringForZeroCoverageCell = s[0] + "\t" + s[1] + "\n"
        centerPointsAsStringForZeroCoverageCell = centerPointsAsStringForZeroCoverageCell.replace('\'',"")
    return gridCellClassifiedAs,ndviTIFFDetailsForZeroCoverageCell,areaOfCoverageForZeroCoverageCell,interceptionForZeroCoverageCell,fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832ZeroCoverageCell,outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells,fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell,calculatedCenterPointInEPSG25832ForZeroCoverageCell,centerPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinatesSystemForZeroCoverageCell,pixelValuesOfCenterPointsOfZeroCoverageCell,centerPointInEPSG4326ForZeroCoveringCell,centerPointOfKeyWindowAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell,averageHeightsForZeroCoverageCell,np.array(_pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell).tolist(),pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt,cntOfNoneKeyWindow,centerPointsAsStringForZeroCoverageCell,CntOfNDVIsWithNanValueInZeroCoverageCell
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , this question is nor minimal not reproducible and contains no debugging details.

Comment: kindly note that the pickle problem is not related to the body of the `run` function but its arguments and return .... everything the argument are return are connected to ... which includes `self` and everything in it, so you shouldn't be passing a class method as target in multiprocessing, as it gives you less control over what is being serialized.

Comment: @AhmedAEK would you please tell me what do you think the problem is then?thanks

Comment: the issue could be that you have wrong 'proceses_count' and '__chunkSize', or it could be the "pickle problem" .... but without debugging detail this is just guesswork.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I double checked the processes count and chunksize, and i found that they are set correctly

Comment: again "correctly" is not a debugging detail, the code above is as "correct" as your "process count" and "chunksize".